# C++ garbage collection

Tags: c++, memory-management, garbage-collection, heap-memory

There are a number of garbage collection libraries for C++.

I am kind of confused how the pointer tracking works.

In particular, suppose we have a base pointer P and a list of other pointers who are computed as offsets from P using an array.

Ex,

P2 = P+offset[0]

How does the garbage collector know P2 is still in scope? It has no direct reference but it's still accessible.

Probably the most popular C++ gc is

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector

But following their example syntax it seems very easy to break so I must not be understanding something.

Comment: why you think it doesn't know `P` and `P2` are same object?

Comment: please add specific library and [mcve]

Comment: each item in the array can be a shared_ptr or similar, the array memory itself will be private and no direct access. P[offset[0]] would return the shared_ptr.

Comment: The garbage collector knows the size of every object (including arrays). A pointer to any address within an object is a pointer to the object, as far as GC is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question cannot be answered in general. There are different systems that may be regarded as garbage collection for C++; for example, [Herb Sutter's deferred_ptr](https://github.com/hsutter/gcpp) is basically a garbage collecting smart pointer.  I've personally implemented [another version of this idea](https://github.com/jwezorek/graph_ptr), similar to Sutter's but less fancy.

I can answer about Boehm, however. How the Boehm garbage collector recognizes pointers when it does its "mark" phase, is basically by scanning memory and assuming that things that look like pointers are pointers.

The garbage collector knows all the areas of memory where user data is and it knows all of the pointers that it has allocated and how big those allocations were. It just looks for chains of pointers starting from "root segments" defined as below, where by "look" we mean explicitly scanning memory for 64 bit values that are the same as one of the GC allocations it has done.

From [here](https://hboehm.info/gc/gcdescr.html):

> Since it cannot generally tell where pointer variables are located, it
> scans the following root segments for pointers:
>
> - The registers. Depending on the architecture, this may be done using    assembly code, or by calling a setjmp-like function which
>   saves    register contents on the stack.
> - The stack(s). In the case of a single-threaded application, on most    platforms this is done by scanning the memory between (an
>   approximation of) the current stack pointer and GC_stackbottom. (For
>   Itanium, the register stack scanned separately.) The GC_stackbottom
>   variable is set in a highly platform-specific way depending on the
>   appropriate configuration information in gcconfig.h. Note that the
>   currently active stack needs to be scanned carefully, since
>   callee-save registers of client code may appear inside collector
>   stack frames, which may change during the mark process. This is
>   addressed by scanning some sections of the stack "eagerly",
>   effectively capturing a snapshot at one point in time.
> - Static data region(s). In the simplest case, this is the region    between DATASTART and DATAEND, as defined in gcconfig.h. However, in
>   most cases, this will also involve static data regions associated
>   with dynamic libraries. These are identified by the mostly
>   platform-specific code in dyn_load.c.

The address space for 64-bit pointers is huge so false positives will be rare, but even if they occur, false positives would just be leaks, that last as long as there happens to be some other variable in the memory the mark phase scans that is exactly the same value as some 64-bit pointer that was allocated by the garbage collector.

Comment: So my example code would result in the gc deleting the object prematurely? Basically explicit pointer addresses must be maintained?

Comment: if your array of pointers were GC allocated and the pointers in the array were GC allocated, it would find those.

Comment: I don't have an array of pointers, I have one pointer and an array of offsets. I should have made that more clear I guess.

Comment: then those could be prematurely deallocated

Comment: but how did you get the pointer + offsets to begin with? You need to have GC_ALLOCATE the pointers to begin with, otherwise they are outside of GC. So you would have had to GC_ALLOCATED a bunch of pointers then threw those pointers away but only stored the possibly negative offsets to an arbitrary other pointer.

Comment: Yes, basically.

Comment: As long as you don't do anything that is *undefined behavior*, such as computing the offsets (difference) of separately allocated objects, the Boehm collector works pretty well.